# Prove that $D ⊂\Bbb R^{n}$ is compact iff whenever {$C_{α}$} is a collection of relatively closed subsets of $D$ with the property $∩ C_{α} = ∅$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functional-analysis, compactness

Prove that $D ⊂\Bbb R^{n}$ is compact if and only if whenever {$C_{α}$} is a collection
of relatively closed subsets of $D$ with the property $∩ C_{α} = ∅$ , there is a finite
subcollection satisfying $C_{α_{j}} = ∅$ .

How to prove this? How is this equal to nonempty? Many theorems show to be "not equal"
Please can you explain clearly?

Comment: This is equivalent to the property that if $\{C_\alpha\}$ is a collection of relatively closed subsets with the property that $\cap_I C_\alpha \neq \emptyset$ for all finite index sets $I$, then $\cap C_\alpha \neq \emptyset$.

Comment: Yes I know what you say. But the question says "being equal" I am confused too much. @copper.hat

Comment: I don't understand what is confusing you?

Comment: How are these two statments -what you said and I said- equivalent? I dont understand. @copper.hat

Comment: I have elaborated my comment below...

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Let $U_\alpha=D\setminus C_\alpha$; then the sets $U_\alpha$ form a relatively open cover of $D$. Now remember that $D$ is compact if and only if every relatively open cover of $D$ has a finite subcover.

**Added:** I’ll do one direction. Suppose that $D$ is compact. Let $\mathscr{C}=\{C_\alpha:\alpha\in I\}$ be a family of relatively closed subsets of $D$ such that $\bigcap\mathscr{C}=\varnothing$. For $\alpha\in I$ let $U_\alpha=D\setminus C_\alpha$, and let $\mathscr{U}=\{U_\alpha:\alpha\in I\}$; then

$$\bigcup\mathscr{U}=\bigcup_{\alpha\in I}U_\alpha=\bigcup_{\alpha\in I}(D\setminus C_\alpha)=D\setminus\bigcap_{\alpha\in I}C_\alpha=D\setminus\bigcap\mathscr{C}=D\;,$$

so $\mathscr{U}$ is an open cover of $D$. Since $D$ is compact, $\mathscr{U}$ has a finite subcover: there is a finite $F\subseteq I$ such that $$\bigcup_{\alpha\in F}U_\alpha=D\;.$$ But then

$$\bigcap_{\alpha\in F}C_\alpha=\bigcap_{\alpha\in F}(D\setminus U_\alpha)=D\setminus\bigcup_{\alpha\in F}U_\alpha=D\setminus D=\varnothing\;,$$

i.e., $\{C_\alpha:\alpha\in F\}$ is a finite subfamily of $\mathscr{C}$ with empty intersection.

Comment: Yes I remember. But how to use in the question. Can you explain more precisely? Because when I think, I am confused too much.

Comment: @B11: I’ve done one direction: if $D$ is compact, then any family of closed sets in $D$ with empty intersection has a finite subfamily with empty intersection. Proving the opposite implication does not require any new ideas beyond the ones that I used.

Comment: Oh ok thank you! When I Will Try to prove the second part, I may ask something. Hope you Will be here..thank you again:)

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer (with apologies to René), it doesn't fit well in a comment.

Let $P_1$ be the property that whenever $\{C_{α}\}$ is a collection
of relatively closed subsets of $D$ with the property $\cap C_{α} = \emptyset$ , there is a finite
subcollection satisfying $C_{α_{j}} = \emptyset$.

Let $P_2$ be the property that whenever $\{C_{α}\}$ is a collection
of relatively closed subsets of $D$ with the property that if $\cap_I C_{α} \neq \emptyset$ for any finite index set $I$, then $\cap C_{α} \neq \emptyset$.

Then $P_1$ iff $P_2$.

($\Rightarrow$): Suppose $\cap_I C_{α} \neq \emptyset$ for any finite index set $I$. If $\cap C_{α} = \emptyset$, then $P_1$ imples that for some finite index set $J$, we have $\cap_J C_{α} = \emptyset$, which is an immediate contradiction. Hence $\cap C_{α} \neq \emptyset$.

($\Leftarrow$): Suppose $\cap C_{α} = \emptyset$, but $\cap_I C_{α} \neq \emptyset$ for any finite index set $I$, then $P_2$ leads to an immediate contradiction.